# The distance between two moving objects at the speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light, speed, distance

Two objects move in the same direction at the speed of light.

If we look at one of these two objects, what does the distance between the two particles change?  Does it stay the same?

Comment: No, two objects *don't* move at the speed of light.

Comment: Massive objects do not move at the speed of light, if they are photons, you cannot attach a reference frame to them to see from their point of view as that would imply you can move to a frame in which the photon was stationary.

Comment: Suppose you asked instead, "two objects moving at 99.9999% of the speed of light." That would be OK. But, moving with respect to what? They're _not_ moving with respect to each other. If your question doesn't mention any other object, then the fact that the two are "moving in the same direction" doesn't mean anything at all. Whatever the answer is for two objects moving in the same direction at 99.9999% of the speed of light, it will be the same as the answer for two objects that are not moving at all.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  It is a hypothesis that the information of an object in the center of the universe (for example, radio waves or reflected light) will reach the edge of the universe ? Or not ??

Comment: Where do you get stuck when you tried to calculate the answer?

Comment: I do not know that according to the facts and opinions of friends, the two objects never meet or that they come closer to the speed of light according to the formula of relative velocity.

Comment: Hint:  For a particle moving with velocity $v$, the location at time $t$ is given by an equation of the form $a+tv$.  (This is the **definition** of constant velocity.)

Comment: Does this classic definition of light speed also apply?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Minkowski (flat) spacetime, in an inertial reference frame, if two massless particles (which necessarily move at the speed of light) are moving in the same direction, then the distance between them will be constant.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.